# Issue with mobile menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to figure out what's wrong with the menu on the mobile version of my website.
I'm using php with bootstrap, and everything works fine, my only issue is the mobile version of the Menu.
[Menu without any issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnMho.png)

When the page loads and I tap on the menu everything looks the way is intended, but when I scroll down the page and try to open the menu up the whole thing is messed up, the menu bar shift on the right side of the screen, but still every touch control (hitboxes) are in the right place.
[Menu with the issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sk3m.png)

I don't know what is wrong, if you guys have any suggestion so I can fix this
let me know!

**HTML and CSS**:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 991px){
  .horizontalMenu>.horizontalMenu-list {
      height: auto;
      min-height: 100%;
      width: 240px;
      background: #cda434;
      padding-bottom: 0;
      margin-left: -240px;
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
  }
  .horizontalMenu>.horizontalMenu-list>li>a.active {
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) !important;
      color: #fff;
  }
  .disable-mobile{
      visibility: hidden;
      display: none;
  }
  .cover-image {
      background-size: cover !important;
      width: 90%;
      position: relative;
  }
}
```

```html
    <div class="header-main">
    <header class="bg-white">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row align-items-center disable-mobile">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12">
                    <div class="d-none d-lg-block mt-2 mb-4">
                        <a class="" href="index.php">
                            <img src="./assets/images/brand/oglialoro.png" class="img-fluid" alt="dashr logo">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 mt-4">
                    <div class="header-icons float-right">
                        <ul class="header-icons-link">
                            <li class="row ">
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <a href="tel:+39 333 864 2639" class="header-icons-link1"><i class="fa text-white fa-phone fa-2x circle-icon"></i></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-9 center-block">
                                    <h6><a href="tel:+39 333 864 2639">+39 333 864 2639</a></h6>
                                    <p class="mb-0">Via Monnet, 2</p>
                                    <p class="mt-0">59100 Prato (PO)</p>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>

                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <!-- Horizontal Header -->
    <div class="mt-2 mb-4 bg-white">
    <div class="horizontal-header clearfix">
        <div class="container">
            <a id="horizontal-navtoggle" class="animated-arrow"><span></span></a>
            <span class="smllogo"><img src="./assets/images/brand/oglialoro.png" width="180"  alt=""/></span>
            <a href="tel:245-6325-3256" class="callusbtn"><i class="fa fa-phone my-color" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /Horizontal Header -->

    <!-- Horizontal Main -->
    <div class="horizontal-main bg-warning clearfix" style="background-color: #cda434 !important;" >
        <div class="horizontal-mainwrapper container">
            <!--Nav-->
            <nav class="horizontalMenu d-md-flex">
                <ul class="horizontalMenu-list">
                    <li aria-haspopup="true" class="small-height hover-mine"><a class="hover-mine text-capitalize text-white font-weight-semibold fs-16 ml-0 mr-0" href="index.php">HOME</a></li>
                    <li aria-haspopup="true" class="small-height"><a class="text-capitalize text-white font-weight-semibold fs-16 ml-0 mr-0" href="contatti.php">CONTATTI</a></li>
                    <li aria-haspopup="true" class="small-height"><a class="text-capitalize text-white font-weight-semibold fs-16 ml-0 mr-0" href="regolamento.php">REGOLAMENTO</a></li>
                    <li aria-haspopup="true" class="small-height"><a class="text-capitalize text-white font-weight-semibold fs-16 ml-0 mr-0" href="lavora-con-noi.php">LAVORA CON NOI</a></li>
                    <li aria-haspopup="true" class="small-height"><a class="text-capitalize text-white font-weight-semibold fs-16 ml-0 mr-0" href="trasporti.php">TRASPORTI</a></li>
                    <li aria-haspopup="true" class="small-height"><a class="text-capitalize text-white font-weight-semibold fs-16 ml-0 mr-0" href="concessionarie.php">CONCESSIONARIE</a></li>
                    <li aria-haspopup="true" class="small-height"><a class="text-capitalize text-white font-weight-semibold fs-16 ml-0 mr-0" href="https://t.me/venditautomotive">OFFERTE TELEGRAM</a></li>
                    <li aria-haspopup="true" class="small-height"><a class="text-capitalize text-white font-weight-semibold fs-16 ml-0 mr-0" href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=393338642639&text=Ciao+sono+un+commerciante%2C+vorrei+essere+inserito+nella+tua+lista.&app_absent=0">OFFERTE WHATSAPP</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <!--Nav-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /Horizontal Main -->
</div>
```

Comment: can you post the css code as well please?

Comment: I've posted my custom css updating my recent post, everything else is bootstrap if you need something specific, just ask @SidNutthi

Answer (score 0):

You should try using the following code in the .horizontalMenu>.horizontalMenu-list tag

```
margin-left: 0%;
```